# Problems with download files from different directories with FTP library Apache Commons

Tags: java, android, download, ftp, apache-commons

I'm working on an application which download images from a FTP server, I'm using the library: Apache commons.

What I want to do is download every image from a tree of directories like this:

-iTable

```
   -imgprod
        *Images here*
   -imgcat
        *Images here*
   -imgmainmen
        *Images here*
   -imgsubmen
        *Images here*
   -standBy
        *Images here*
```

One path example would be: /iTable/imgprod/myImg.jpg

I connect to the root of the server and I stay there, I don't move through the directories, I have the paths and I only list the files inside and then donwload the images. The imgprod and standBy directories are different, for imgprod I have the complete path that I obtained from other side and what I do in the standBy is list the files inside and donwload every single file which is a .jpg or a .png.

I've use Filezilla to verify that the access is correct and paths are ok.

The problem that I have is: I download the images of imgmainmen correctly, in imgsubm and imgcat there are not any images, it's all right until here, but when it tries to download the product(imgprod) it downloads nothing, I have the file but it has 0 bytes. After that, is the standBy's turn and I list the files inside the standBy directory, but I obtain 0 files.

Like I said, I've looked for the images with Filezilla and I see them and I could download every image.

I leave my code here:

```
        String remote;
        OutputStream outputStream;
        File download;
        boolean down = false;

        client.connect(host,port);
        Log.e("LOGGIN", host + " " + port);
        client.login(user,pass);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        Log.e("CONNECTED","YES");
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


        //STEP1: Obtaining main menu
        FTPFile[] mainmenu= client.listFiles("/iTable/imgmainmen/");
        if(mainmenu.length>0){
            for (String current : menuImg){

                if(mainmenu.length > 0){
                    remote = "/iTable/imgmainmen/"+current;

                    download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImgsMainMenu+"/"+current);

                    download.deleteOnExit();

                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(download));
                    client.retrieveFile(remote,outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    down = false;


                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        //STEP2: Obtaining submenu
        FTPFile[] submenu= client.listFiles("/iTable/imgsubm/");
        if(submenu.length > 0){
            for (String current : submenuImg){


                if(submenu.length > 0){
                    remote = "/iTable/imgsubm/"+current;

                    download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImgsMainMenu+"/"+current);

                    download.deleteOnExit();

                    download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImagessub+"/"+current);
                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(download));
                    client.retrieveFile(remote,outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    down = false;



                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //STEP3: Obtaining category
        FTPFile[] category= client.listFiles("/iTable/imgcat/");
        if(category.length > 0){
            for (String current : categoryImg){
                if(category.length > 0){
                    remote = "/iTable/imgcat/"+current;

                    download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImgsMainMenu+"/"+current);

                    download.deleteOnExit();

                    download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImagenesCat+"/"+current);
                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(download));
                    client.retrieveFile(remote,outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    down = false;



                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //STEP4: Obtaining products
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : product.entrySet()){
            //Verifying if the image is PNG or JPG
            String[] route = entry.getValue().split("\\\\");
            String image = route[route.length-1];
            String[] extension = image.split("\\.");

            download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImgsProd+"/"+entry.getKey()+"."+extension[1]);
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(download));
            client.retrieveFile(entry.getKey(),outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        }

        //STEP5: Obtaining standby
        //list the files inside
        FTPFile[] standbys = client.listFiles("/iTable/standBy");

        if(standbys.length > 0){

            SharedData.setStandByNumber(standbys.length, context);

            for(int i = 1; i<=standbys.length; i++){

                String extension = standbys[i-1].getName().substring(standbys[i-1].getName().length()-4);

                Log.e("EXTENSION",extension);
                if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".png") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg")){
                    remote = "/iTable/standBy/"+standbys[i-1].getName();
                    download = new File(CustomConstants.urlImgsStandBy+"/sl"+i+extension);
                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(download));
                    client.retrieveFile(remote,outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    Log.e("IMAGES",download.getAbsolutePath()+download.getName());
                    imagesSB.add(download.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `The imgprod and standBy directories are different, in imgprod I have the complete path that I obtained from other side a` ??? I have no idea what that would be "a complete path in a directory" Nor do i have any idea what you mean by  "other side". Please update your post. Write it clear.

Comment: `FTPFile[] mainmenu= client.listFiles("/iTable/imgmainmen/");` >??? You wrote six times the same code for six directories. That is no programming. You should start with a list of paths and then use a loop to handle all paths of the list. If directories should be handled differently you could start with two lists.

Comment: Anyhow it does not make sense to post six times the same code. Post only code for a directory that gives problems. Remove the rest please. Code for one directory should do.

Comment: @greenapps I wrote it several times to explain that, eventhough i use the same code, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: @greenapps Also, what i mean with "other side" is that i get the absolute path from a database, and that is what i use to access the images.

Comment: It makes no sense to post your problem in this way. And why would it matter how you obtained the paths? If it is a valid path then further thats irrelevant. And further i still do not understand what that means: "in imgprod I have the complete path that I obtained from other side a ??? I have no idea what that would be "in imgprod I have the complete path "..

Comment: @greenapps I mean "for", sorry. I have the right path for the imgprod directory. I explained that just to clarify that the path is correct, that's all.